# When I access mysite I get the cannot load user profile

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

Hi I've create mysite successfull but when I try and access the site collection i get this error:

> User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User
>   Profile Application:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
>   UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
>   does not have 86be0f20-0a31-4514-ae30-0319f57136a1      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext
>   serviceContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly caused by missing permissions. Please make sure the following service-accounts have full control to your UserProfileService Application:

- MySites WebApplication Pool account
- Distributed Cache service account (can be found in services.msc at "AppFabric Caching Service")
- If it still doesn't work, also add the serviceaccount for the UserProfileService

Comment: Noted lets say my MySites WebApplication Pool Acc is "Charles" should Charles be used for AppFabric Caching  and be added on the UserProfile services? with full control.

Comment: Please do not use "charles" as the AppFabric Service Account. You should use a separate account. If you want to change it, please follow the steps described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#changesvcacct.